# Como obtengo los valores de una funcion para utilizarlos en otra

Tags: javascript, json

Tengo esta función que hace un llamado a un php donde se realiza una consulta, el caso es que esta función retorna un array con los datos de la consulta:

```
function datosDis(folio) {

   $.ajax({
        url: 'peticiones/consultaRepDis.php',
        data: { 'Folio': folio },
        type: 'POST',
        success:  function (res) {
            let datos = JSON.parse(res)
            folio= datos.data.map(fila =>{
                console.log(fila)
                return fila.folio;
            })
        }, 
    });
```

Y lo que necesito es obtener los valores de la función para utilizarlos en un en otra función, lo intente salvar los datos de la siguiente manera pero no me funciono:

```
$('#frmRecepcionDistribuidor').submit(function (e) {

let datos = datosDis(folio);
console.log(datos);
```

});

Comment: Hola. Las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas. Debes trabajar la respuesta dentro del `success` o bien llamar desde ahí la función pasándole a `res` o implementar lo que se conoce como *callback*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utiliza el [*callback*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Callback_function), en resumen es una función que se pasa como argumento a otra función y será llamada cuando la otra función se haya completado.

```
function datosDis(folio, callback) {
   $.ajax({
        url: 'peticiones/consultaRepDis.php',
        data: { 'Folio': folio },
        type: 'POST',
        success:  function (res) {
            let datos = JSON.parse(res)
            folio= datos.data.map(fila =>{
                console.log(fila)
                return fila.folio;
            })
            callback(datos);
        }, 
    });
}

$('#frmRecepcionDistribuidor').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  datosDis(folio, function(datos) {
    console.log(datos);
  });
});
```

Ahora la function `datosDis` tiene dos argumentos, `folio` y `callback`.
El callback solo será llamado cuando la función datosDis haya sido completada.

En el `submit`, se pasan 2 argumentos, el folio y el callback, a la función datosDis. datosDis realiza la solicitud HTTP a peticiones/consultaRepDis.php; una vez que esta solicitud se haya completado, la función datosDis devuelve los datos. El callback recibe un argumento, y luego imprime los datos

Otra posibilidad que puede resolver es utilizar [*async await*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), convirtiendo la función datosDis en una función async.
De esta manera, la función datosDis realiza la solicitud de forma asíncrona. Cuando la solicitud se completa, retorna los datos y el envío del formulario invoca la función datosDis y espera el resultado, una vez que este retorna, submit imprime los datos.

```
async function datosDis(folio) {
  let datos;
  try {
    datos = await $.ajax({
      url: 'peticiones/consultaRepDis.php',
      data: { 'Folio': folio },
      type: 'POST',
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  return datos;
}

$('#frmRecepcionDistribuidor').submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let datos = await datosDis(folio);
  console.log(datos);
});
```

Comment: El callback dentro de submit también debiera ser async, no crees

Comment: Muchas gracias, utilice lo del callback y me funciono a la perfección.